# Is there a way to put the iPhone into a child-only mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, children

I find that my two-year-old will often delete photos...most of the times by accident.

Is there a mode on the iPhone or some other software that will help thwart this?

Is there a way to control which apps a child can access?

(I'm hoping that Apple would build it right into the OS.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, start with [Guided Access](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5509) which easily [locks one app in full screen mode](http://help.apple.com/iphone/7/#/iph7fad0d10) and then move on to [restrictions](http://help.apple.com/iphone/7/#/iph9b66575d5) once you have a feeling for what you want to open up past one app at a time as your two year old gets more able to use more than just one game at a time..

Comment: Guided Access worked like a charm! How do I use Restriction with Guided Access to allow multiple apps access?

Comment: When using guided access, you will not be able to switch between apps, so you will have to use one or another.