# Timer Lockout for iOS allowing multiple apps

Tags: ios, ipad, children

Is there a way to force the iPad to lock after X minutes but also allow my kids to use multiple apps? I know about [guided access](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/107538/91660) which works great at locking them to one app (e.g., for homework) but sometimes I want to give them flexible time to use whatever app or game they want.

Comment: No. Apple only allows Guided Access, no timeout.

Comment: Actually, that's not correct. See below.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free and [very simple way](http://samluce.com/2014/09/apps-limit-childs-time-ipad/) to limit time on iOS if you have an activation passcode.

- Launch the Clock app
- Set a Timer
- Make sure that "Stop Playing" is set under "Sounds."

If a sound is set, naturally that plays. If "Stop Playing" is set, the device will go to the lock screen. Naturally, this will require your passcode or fingerprint!

This technique allows another user (my kids in this case) to use whatever apps they want, but only for a set amount of time until they need my passcode. You can also use guided access (linked above) to restrict them to only one app.